# How do I disable the Branch selection at the top of Journal Transactions

Tags: acumatica

I'm looking to disable the Branch selection at the top of the Journal Transactions screen.  I've looked at the source code, but I can't see anything for that particular selection.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to invoke `PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled` method in the RowSelected handler as shown in the code snippet below?

```
public class JournalEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<JournalEntry>
{
    public void Batch_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Batch batch = e.Row as Batch;
        if (batch == null) return;

        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<Batch.branchID>(sender, batch, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry - I should have clarified.  That I would be able to figure out, but it's the dropdown at the very top of the screen (see screenshot I added to original question above) - since it doesn't have any DAC associated with it, I wasn't sure how to handle it...

Comment: It is not possible to disable the current Brach drop-down via customization. Instead consider restricting access rights on the branch level as explained in  the **Branch Security Administration** section of the **S110 Security Management** training course.